# Tengo GeneXus 9.0 kb lenguaje RPG, no me crea el nombre o Texto del archivo físico y lógico en el as400 o iSiries

Tags: genexus, as400

Ayuda no me crea el nombre o descripción de la tabla o archivo físico y lógico en el as400 o ISeries, pantalla adjunta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente eso es así, GeneXus no coloca texto descriptivo ni para tablas ni para indices cuando se crean.